# Possible to explain code flow in this example ?? Memory leak? Where?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, ios4

Referring to this PageControl example could somebody please explain the code flow? Instruments is giving me a leak here so looking for some help.

Re: this tutorial:
http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone/

We init an array to Null objects in our AppDidFinishLaunching method...

```
NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (unsigned i = 0; i < kNumberOfPages; i++) {
    [controllers addObject:[NSNull null]];
}
self.viewControllers = controllers;
[controllers release];
```

and then call:

```
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:0];
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:1];
```

Here is the implementation for *loadScrollViewWithPage*:

```
- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page {
if (page < 0) return;
if (page >= kNumberOfPages) return;

PageControlExampleViewControl *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null]) {
    controller = [[PageControlExampleViewControl alloc] initWithPageNumber:page];
    [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
    [controller release];
}

if (nil == controller.view.superview) {
    CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    controller.view.frame = frame;
    [scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
}
}
```

Instruments is giving me a leak in this implementation on the following line:

*if (nil == controller.view.superview) {*

Anyone know why this would be a reported leak in Instruments? My code is identical.
Also after the initial call *[self loadScrollViewWithPage:0];*, on the first pass through and creating the object, **BOTH** *if clauses* are passed and entered.

How is this possible? **If** we enter the first *if clause*, we alloc and create our controller and end by **releasing* it (*[controller release]*).

Shouldn't the next line (*if (nil == controller.view.superview)*) produce an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error seeing as we just RELEASED *controller* above?

SCREENSHOT FROM INSTRUMENTS:
[image: Instruments screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why Instruments would be reporting a leak on that line, unless it's just noticing that controller.view was allocated by that line (accessing a UIViewController's view property automatically loads the view if necessary) and not yet freed (which it shouldn't be as long as scrollView exists and controller.view remains as a subview of it).

It is correct that it goes through both `if` clauses. The first `if` checks whether a view controller actually exists for that page index, and if not it creates one (but *does not* add it to the scrollView). The second checks if the view for the view controller for the page index has already been added to the scrollView, and if not it adds it.

The reason it does not crash is because `[viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller]` adds the controller to an NSMutableArray, which retains the controller. It might be slightly less confusing to do it like this instead:

```
if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null]) {
    controller = [[[PageControlExampleViewControl alloc] initWithPageNumber:page] autorelease];
    [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
}
```

Comment: Added screenshot of instruments output for the affected line. I really have no idea why this is leaking because as you say. At the line it is leaking though _controller.view_ is **not** a subview of of the scrollview yet? It adds it in that clause it's about to enter?

Comment: From your screenshot, it is complaining about the allocated view. The line reporting the leak is the last line in your program before the view is allocated. Are you leaking scrollView at some point? That could cause Instruments to count all its subviews as leaked as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are not properly releasing the scrollView.

Answer (score 0):

> How is this possible? If we enter the first if clause, we alloc and create our controller and end by *releasing it ([controller release]).
>
> Shouldn't the next line (if (nil == controller.view.superview)) produce an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error seeing as we just RELEASED controller above?

look at the line between alloc and release.

```
[viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
```

the viewControllers array will retain the controller.

But imho it's no good code. for exactly the reason you've stated. Not very clear at first sight.

Comment: My understanding was that the viewControllers will retain the ViewController yes, but since the _[controller release]_, it should no longer be accessible through that *controller pointer should it? Only through [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page] ?

Comment: When an object is retained its location in the memory stays the same. And the controller pointer still references the same address in the memory. a release does neither change the pointer nor the address of the object. That's why we get all the BAD_ACCESS bugs.

Comment: So is the _[controller]_ release call redundant and unnecessary there since we're retaining the object anyway by putting it into the array?

Comment: nope, not redundant. The rules say if you alloc you have to release. when you remove the object from the array it will be deallocated because it's not retained anymore. If you wouldn't release it in that line it would be retained twice. One time because of your alloc, and another time because of the array. Removing from the array would lower the retain count. But it would hang around forever because it's not 0. - You could release it when you remove it from the array. But that code would be even more confusing than referencing after a release. So you should never do something like that.

Comment: added a screenshot to original of my instruments output. It really baffles me :)